# PHP Implode with breakpoints

Tags: php, implode

Is there a way to implode with breakpoints

```
$a1 = array('a1','a2','a3','a4');
implode("<br/>",$a1);
```

I am expecting the output something like this

```
a1<br/>
a2<br/>
a3<br/>
a4<br/>
```

I am getting Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: $str=implode("<br/>",$a1);   echo $str; should work... Which php version you use, this is interesting...

Comment: wrap in single quote ' not "

Comment: I tried implode('<br/>',$a1)  still I get invalid arguments.. I am using PHP5

Comment: In your real code `$a1` is really an array? Maybe it's string or something else?

Comment: Sorry.. This I added to demonstrate the issue.. But logic I was trying to code did not initialized properly

Answer (score 2):

This produces exactly the result you want to:

```
$a1 = array('a1','a2','a3','a4');
$result=implode("<br/>\n",$a1)."<br/>";

echo $result;

/**
a1<br/>
a2<br/>
a3<br/>
a4<br/>
*/
```

working demo : http://3v4l.org/PWVTb

Implode by using the string `"<br/>"` plus the new line character `\n`. Also adding a `"<br/>"` string at the end.

Thats how i understood your question, if i misunderstood let me know. Anyway, the result is *exactly* what you asked.

Comment: it works...My mistake was  $a1  was not initialized to  array....I tried executing the code it is working